# How do you find the 6th root using primitive expressions in Scheme?

Tags: functional-programming, scheme, racket

By primitive expressions, I mean `+ - * / sqrt`, unless there are others that I am missing. I'm wondering how to write a Scheme expression that finds the 6th root using only these functions.

I know that I can find the cube root of the square root, but cube root doesn't appear to be a primitive expression.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider [expt](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/generic-numbers.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._expt%29%29), passing in a fractional power as its second argument.

But let's say we didn't know about `expt`.  Could we still compute it?

One way to do it is by applying something like [Newton's method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method).  For example, let's say we wanted to compute n^(1/4).  Of course, we already know we can just take the `sqrt` twice to do this, but let's see how Newton's method may apply to this problem.

Given `n`, we'd like to discover roots `x` of the function:

```
f(x) = x^4 - n
```

Concretely, if we wanted to look for `16^(1/4)`, then we'd look for a root for the function:

```
f(x) = x^4 - 16
```

We already know if we plug in `x=2` in there, we'll discover that `2` is a root of this function.  But say that we didn't know that.  How would we discover the `x` values that make this function zero?

Newton's method says that if we have a guess at `x`, call it `x_0`, we can improve that guess by doing the following process:

```
x_1 = x_0 - f(x_0) / f'(x_0)
```

where `f'(x)` is notation for the [derivative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative) of `f(x)`.  For the case above, the derivative of `f(x)` is `4x^3`.

And we can get better guesses `x_2`, `x_3`, ... by repeating the computation:

```
x_2 = x_1 - f(x_1) / f'(x_1)
x_3 = x_2 - f(x_2) / f'(x_2)
...
```

until we get tired.

Let's write this all in code now:

```
(define (f x)
  (- (* x x x x) 16))

(define (f-prime x)
  (* 4 x x x))

(define (improve guess)
  (- guess (/ (f guess)
              (f-prime guess))))

(define approx-quad-root-of-16
  (improve (improve (improve (improve (improve 1.0))))))
```

The code above just expresses `f(x)`, `f'(x)`, and the idea of improving an initial guess five times.  Let's see what the value of `approx-quad-root-of-16` is:

```
> approx-quad-root-of-16
2.0457437305170534
```

Hey, cool.  It's actually doing something, and it's close to `2`.  Not bad for starting with such a bad first guess of `1.0`.

Of course, it's a little silly to hardcode `16` in there.  Let's generalize, and turn it into a function that takes an arbitrary `n` instead, so we can compute the quad root of anything:

```
(define (approx-quad-root-of-n n)
  (define (f x)
    (- (* x x x x) n))

  (define (f-prime x)
    (* 4 x x x))

  (define (improve guess)
    (- guess (/ (f guess)
                (f-prime guess))))

  (improve (improve (improve (improve (improve 1.0))))))
```

Does this do something effective?  Let's see:

```
> (approx-quad-root-of-n 10)
1.7800226459895
> (expt (approx-quad-root-of-n 10) 4)
10.039269440807693
```

Cool: it is doing something useful.  But note that it's not that precise yet.  To get better precision, we should keep calling `improve`, and not just four or five times.  Think loops or recursion: repeat the improvement till the solution is "close enough".

This is a sketch of how to solve these kinds of problems.  For a little more detail, look at [the section on computing square roots in Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/sicp/book/node12.html).

Answer (score 2):

You may want to try out a numeric way, which may be inefficient for larger numbers, but it works.

Also if you also count `pow` as a primitive (since you also count `sqrt`) you could do this:

```
pow(yournum, 1/6);
```

Comment: Note that in Scheme, you're probably looking for the `expt` function.  Examples: http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/generic-numbers.html#(def._((quote._~23~25kernel)._expt))

Comment: Yes, sorry. I'm not very familiar with functional programming in general... :)